# Are there any mods that make the helicopters in Crysis behave in a more "realistic" manner?

Tags: mods, crysis

I've recently picked up Crysis on Steam and have noticed that the helicopters exhibit some very annoying behaviour. They seem to be able to spot you from miles away, regardless of whether you are hiding or cloaked (fair enough if they have IR sensors, but it's no fun if you can't hide), and while their shots do very little damage, they come in extremely rapid succession. Basically they are a pain and feel a little out of context with the rest of the game. Are there any mods that improve their behaviour?

The helicopters in Half Life 2 were always an enjoyable fight, whereas these are most definitely not.

Comment: Though, they were really annoying, I had no problem with hiding from them and they did not find me while cloaked. Though, yes, they easily spot you, I find it a very hard and interesting exercise to hide from them and lay out even traps by uncloaking, cloaking and changing position to maneuver them into the right location.

Answer (score 1):

I once searched for the same thing, and I couldn't find anything like that.

So my answer is no, there aren't any mods for this (at least as of now)